# I am having trouble sorting this program in python it gives me an error when i sort the list of an object

Tags: string, function, sorting, object

import random

class Student(object):
"""Represents a student."""

```
def __init__(self, name, number=100):
    """All scores are initially 0."""
    self.name = name
    self.scores = []
    for count in range(number):
        self.scores.append(0)

def getName(self):
    """Returns the student's name."""
    return self.name

def setScore(self, i, score):
    """Resets the ith score, counting from 1."""
    self.scores[i - 1] = score

def getScore(self, i):
    """Returns the ith score, counting from 1."""
    return self.scores[i - 1]

def getAverage(self):
    """Returns the average score."""
    return sum(self.scores) / len(self._scores)

def getHighScore(self):
    """Returns the highest score."""
    return max(self.scores)

def String(self):
    """Returns the string representation of the student."""
    return "Name: " + self.name + "\nScores: " + " ".join(map(str, self.scores))
```

def main():
studentName = []
while True:
NumberOfStudent = input("how many student in classroom: ")
if NumberOfStudent.isdigit():
NumberOfStudent = int(NumberOfStudent)
break
else:
print ("please input a number")
for count in reversed (range(NumberOfStudent)):
print (count)
Name = input('student name: ')
student = Student(Name + str(count+1),10)
studentName.append(student)

```
random.shuffle(studentName)    
studentName.sort()
```

if **name** == "**main**":
main()

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Student' and 'Student'

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
 , line 73, in <module>
    main()
  , line 59, in main
    print(studentName.sort())
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Student' and 'Student'

Comment: okay i got it to run thank you that helped a lot